# Finding longest chain in poset in subquadratic time

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, partial-order

Let $(A,\leq)$ be some finite poset. For $a,a' \in A$ we can determine in constant time whether or not $a \leq a'$. The *height* of an $A$ is by definition the greatest $n$ such that there are elements
$$
a_0 < a_1 < \cdots < a_n
$$
of $A$. By treating $(A,\leq)$ as a directed acyclic graph, we can determine the height of $A$ as the length of the longest path in this graph, which we can compute in linear time in the size of the graph; that is, in $\mathcal O(|A|^2)$.

Can we do any better for this special case where $A$ is a poset?

Edit: if it matters, I am especially interested in the case where the length of the longest path is already known to be significantly shorter than the size of $A$.

Comment: Are you sure you have a _partially_ ordered set? You mention that for $a, a' \in A$ you have an order. Is that for __all__ $a, a'$ or?

Comment: @orlp, for all $a,a'$ we can determine whether or not $a \leq a'$; but if we find $a \not \leq a'$ that does not mean that $a' \leq a$ must hold. Obviously the question does not make sense when $A$ is totally ordered, as then the answer is always $|A|-1$.

Comment: Maybe I'm still misunderstanding exactly what you meant. Either way I undeleted my answer, but if it's not correct because of some wrong assumption feel free to comment on it explaining why and I'll delete it.

Comment: @orlp, as also pointed out by chi, I am not sure where you are getting the total order from. The set $A$ is typically not totally ordered. The only thing I mention in my post is that the partial order relation $\leq$ is decidable in constant time, which has nothing in particular to do with totality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, start by observing that

when A has no comparable pairs, the height will be 0

and
when A has one or two comparable pairs, the height will be 1

.
Thus, when ​ $\leq$ ​ is given with one bit for each ordered-pair of distinct elements,

even [promised-to-be-at-most-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Promise_problem) height will have

co-nondeterministic query complexity ​ $(|\hspace{.02 in}A|\hspace{-0.03 in}\cdot \hspace{-0.03 in}(|\hspace{.02 in}A|\hspace{-0.04 in}-\hspace{-0.05 in}1))\hspace{.02 in}/\hspace{.02 in}2$

and probabilistic query complexity ​ [$\Theta$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Family_of_Bachmann.E2.80.93Landau_notations)$\left(\hspace{-0.02 in}|\hspace{.02 in}A|^2\right)$ .

Accordingly, we can only hope for better when ​ $\leq$ ​ is given in some other way,

like as a list of the pairs for which it's true or as

an $A$-indexed array of ordered-pairs of lists, such that for each element $a$ of $A$,

$a$'s left list is the $a'$ such that ​ $a' < a$ ​ and $a$'s right list is the $a'$ such that ​ $a < a'$

.
(I currently have no clue regarding the complexity for such representations of ​ $\leq$ .)

For your case of interest:

See [this question](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/36526/6973) and its answer.

(That answer's universe size is your n and that answer's n is your ​ $|\hspace{.04 in}A|$ .)

However, that negative result does not necessarily apply to

"the case where the length of the longest path is already known to be" short.

Comment: Thank you! Actually, my case of interest had more structure (it is a subset of the boolean algebra $\{0,1\}^n$ with the induced ordering -- that is, a set of bit strings ordered pointwise) but it didn't immediately seem relevant to me. With this answer I see that I really need to dive into the structure of the kind of $A$ I care about.

Comment: (I just edited my answer, and don't know whether-or-not stackexchange will inform you of that.) ​ ​

Comment: Thank you for the update, but they are talking about anti-chains while I am talking about chains -- or is there a symmetry that I am missing?

Comment: By definition, a set $S$ is an anti-chain if and only if there are _no_ elements ​ $a_0,a_1$ ​ of $S$ such that ​ $a_0 < a_1$ . ​ ​ ​ ​